# Tracking - hide empty track when tracking fails

Tags: tracking

I'm using motion tracking in blender to attach objects on a video file using [Link Empty to Track](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/movie_clip/tracking/clip/editing/reconstruction.html).

I'd like to understand if there's an automatic way to hide objects when a linked track stops to track a feature in the input file.

I've manually disabled rendering for the childobjects setting key frames by hand, but is a tedious process if you need to repeat it for many tracks.

I’d like to understand if there’s a sort of state that I can use to disable tracks’ child objects when tracking stops moving.